# Using SSL in Apache Camel Netty component with JVM default KeyStore file

Tags: java, ssl, jvm

I could not manage to find a way to make Camel use JVM's loaded KeyStore file instead of specifing the exact location as the following code example which was taken from Camel's Netty component documentation:

```
KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
ksp.setResource("/users/home/server/keystore.jks");
ksp.setPassword("keystorePassword");

KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
kmp.setKeyPassword("keyPassword");

SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

NettyComponent nettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("netty", NettyComponent.class);
nettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
```

What I actually want to achieve, if possible, is avoiding all (or most) of the above code by telling Camel to load the default JVM keystore settings.

Thanks